# How do I Display all data after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using  [bootstrap-table by wenzhixin](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)  on Github it is  [this one](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)

I want to do a button that would toggle filter, Filtering works but when I try do display all the Data again In does not Work, I have struggled with this issue in two days but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried

1. `$('#table').bootstrapTable('load', $('#table').bootstrapTable('getData'));` but It doesn't work it seems that getData gives the already filtered data
2. `$('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data);`
   where data is the array of my Data but it does not change anything
3. I wanted to use `$('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh')` ,but It does not support local data.

Here is my JSFiddler https://jsfiddle.net/pacitwizere/4y3079s7/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data variable will not be updated by bootstrapTable filterBy feature. Adding the following line to your click functions will make it work.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable("filterBy", )

$('#table').bootstrapTable("filterBy", {"forks_count": ["11","4"]})
```

How about this?
https://jsfiddle.net/4y3079s7/4/

Comment: My Question is not with filtering , but it is the issue of displaying all the data again after filtering, The JsFiddler you provided anly does filtering but it does not display all the data again, so it does not answer the question @Chris

Comment: $('#table').bootstrapTable("filterBy", ) will do the trick for you : ) updated my jsfiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/4y3079s7/4/

Comment: Perfect This answers my Question, I could vote up but no reputation. Thank you very much @Chris